Bug only manifests on FreeBSD, but works perfectly fine on Windows, Linux, and MacOS
Here's the relevant part of the code from an arena allocator:
#ifdef DEBUG
    #include <string.h>
    #define D(x) x
#else
    #define D(x) (void) 0
#endif

/* Allocates a pointer from `arena`.
 *
 * The allocated pointer is at least aligned to `alignment`.
 *
 * `alignment` must be a power of 2.
 * 
 * `size` must be a multiple of `alignment`.
 *
 * If a request can not be entertained, i.e. would overflow, or `arena` is full,
 * the function returns `nullptr`. The function also returns a `nullptr` if the 
 * requested `size` or `alignment` is 0 or if `alignment` is not a power of 2, 
 * or if `size` is not a multiple of `alignment`.
 *
 * Any allocations made prior to this call are not freed on failure, and remain 
 * valid until the arena is either reset or destroyed. */
void *arena_alloc(Arena *arena, size_t alignment, size_t size)
{
    if (size == 0
        || alignment == 0 || (alignment != 1 && !is_power_of_two(alignment))
        || !is_multiple_of(size, alignment)) {
        return nullptr;
    }

    M_Pool *curr_pool = arena->pools[arena->current - 1];
    uint8_t *const p = curr_pool->buf + curr_pool->offset;
    const uintptr_t original = ((uintptr_t) p);

    if (original > UINTPTR_MAX - alignment) {
        return nullptr;
    }

    const uintptr_t remain = original & (alignment - 1);
    const uintptr_t aligned =
        remain != 0 ? original + (alignment - remain) : original;
    const size_t offset = aligned - original;

    if (size > SIZE_MAX - offset) {
        return nullptr;
    }

    size += offset;

    if (size > curr_pool->buf_len - curr_pool->offset) {
        return nullptr;
    }

    /* Set the optional padding for alignment immediately before a user block, 
     * and the bytes immediately following such a block to non-zero. 
     * The intent is to trigger OBOB failures to inappropiate app use of 
     * strlen()/strnlen(), which keep forging ahead till encountering ascii NUL. */
    D(
        /* 0xA5 is used in FreeBSD's PHK malloc for debugging purposes. */
        if (remain) {
            memset(p + (alignment - remain), 0xA5, alignment - remain);
        }
    );

    curr_pool->offset += size;
    D(memset(curr_pool->buf + curr_pool->offset, 0xA5,
            curr_pool->buf_len - curr_pool->offset));

    arena->last_alloc_size = size;

    /* Equal to "aligned", but preserves provenance. */
    return p + offset;
}

And here are the unit tests for this function:
static void test_arena_alloc(void)
{
    Arena *const arena = arena_new(nullptr, 100);

    TEST_ASSERT(arena);

    TEST_CHECK(arena_alloc(arena, 1, 112) == nullptr);
    TEST_CHECK(arena_alloc(arena, 0, 1) == nullptr);
    TEST_CHECK(arena_alloc(arena, 1, 0) == nullptr);
    TEST_CHECK(arena_alloc(arena, 2, 5) == nullptr);
    TEST_CHECK(arena_alloc(arena, 3, 5) == nullptr);

    TEST_CHECK(arena_alloc(arena, 1, 95));
    uint8_t *const curr_pool = arena->pools[0]->buf;

    TEST_CHECK(curr_pool[96] == 0xA5 && curr_pool[97] == 0xA5
        && curr_pool[98] == 0xA5 && curr_pool[99] == 0xA5);

    arena_reset(arena);

#ifdef HAVE_STDALIGN_H
    const int *const a = arena_alloc(arena, alignof (int), 5 * sizeof *a);
    const double *const b = arena_alloc(arena, alignof (double), 2 * sizeof *b);
    const char *const c = arena_alloc(arena, 1, 10);
    const short *const d = arena_alloc(arena, alignof (short), 5 * sizeof *d);

    TEST_CHECK(a && is_aligned(a, alignof (int)));
    TEST_CHECK(b && is_aligned(b, alignof (double)));
    TEST_CHECK(c && is_aligned(c, 1));
    TEST_CHECK(d && is_aligned(d, alignof (short)));
#endif
    arena_destroy(arena);
}

On Linux (Ubuntu and Linux Mint), Windows 10 and Windows 11, and MacOS (macos-latest, whatever version Github Actions use) all of these pass without a problem.
cc -std=c11 -fPIC -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wwrite-strings -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-parentheses -Wpedantic -Warray-bounds -Wno-unused-function -Wstrict-prototypes -Wdeprecated -DDEBUG    tests.c   -o tests
./tests arena_alloc --verbose=3
Test arena_alloc:
  tests.c:92: arena... ok
  tests.c:94: arena_alloc(arena, 1, 112) == nullptr... ok
  tests.c:95: arena_alloc(arena, 0, 1) == nullptr... ok
  tests.c:96: arena_alloc(arena, 1, 0) == nullptr... ok
  tests.c:97: arena_alloc(arena, 2, 5) == nullptr... ok
  tests.c:98: arena_alloc(arena, 3, 5) == nullptr... ok
  tests.c:100: arena_alloc(arena, 1, 95)... ok
  tests.c:103: curr_pool[96] == 0xA5 && curr_pool[97] == 0xA5 && curr_pool[98] == 0xA5 && curr_pool[99] == 0xA5... ok
  tests.c:125: a && is_aligned(a, alignof (int))... ok
  tests.c:126: b && is_aligned(b, alignof (double))... ok
  tests.c:127: c && is_aligned(c, 1)... ok
  tests.c:128: d && is_aligned(d, alignof (short))... ok
  SUCCESS: All conditions have passed.

Summary:
  Count of run unit tests:           1
  Count of successful unit tests:    1
  Count of failed unit tests:        0
SUCCESS: No unit tests have failed.

Yet if I compile this code on FreeBSD, one test fail:
Test arena_alloc:
  tests.c:92: arena... ok
  tests.c:94: arena_alloc(arena, 1, 112) == nullptr... ok
  tests.c:95: arena_alloc(arena, 0, 1) == nullptr... ok
  tests.c:96: arena_alloc(arena, 1, 0) == nullptr... ok
  tests.c:97: arena_alloc(arena, 2, 5) == nullptr... ok
  tests.c:98: arena_alloc(arena, 3, 5) == nullptr... ok
  tests.c:100: arena_alloc(arena, 1, 95)... ok
  tests.c:104: curr_pool[96] == 0xA5 && curr_pool[97] == 0xA5 && curr_pool[98] == 0xA5 && curr_pool[99] == 0xA5... failed
  tests.c:114: a && is_aligned(a, alignof (int))... ok
  tests.c:115: b && is_aligned(b, alignof (double))... ok
  tests.c:116: c && is_aligned(c, 1)... ok
  tests.c:117: d && is_aligned(d, alignof (short))... ok
  FAILED: 1 condition has failed.

If I print out the values of curr_pool[96]-curr_pool[99], all of them are 0, and not 0xA5.
This is the Makefile I am using, which defines the DEBUG flag:
CFLAGS += -std=c11
CFLAGS += -fPIC
CFLAGS += -Wall
CFLAGS += -Wextra
CFLAGS += -Werror
CFLAGS += -Wwrite-strings
CFLAGS += -Wno-unused-variable
CFLAGS += -Wno-parentheses
CFLAGS += -Wpedantic
CFLAGS += -Warray-bounds
CFLAGS += -Wno-unused-function
CFLAGS += -Wstrict-prototypes
CFLAGS += -Wdeprecated


TARGET := arena
TEST_TARGET := tests
SLIB_TARGET := libarena.a
DLIB_TARGET := libarena.so

RM := /bin/rm -f

release: CFLAGS += -O2 -s -DTEST_MAIN
release: $(TARGET)

debug: CFLAGS += -DTEST_MAIN -DDEBUG -g3 -ggdb -fsanitize=address,leak,undefined
debug: $(TARGET)

static: $(SLIB_TARGET)

$(SLIB_TARGET): $(TARGET).o
    $(AR) rcs $@ $^

shared: $(DLIB_TARGET)
shared: LDFLAGS += -shared

$(DLIB_TARGET): $(TARGET).o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

test: CFLAGS += -DDEBUG
test: $(TEST_TARGET)
    ./$(TEST_TARGET) --verbose=3

clean: 
    $(RM) $(TARGET) $(TEST_TARGET) $(TARGET).o $(SLIB_TARGET) $(DLIB_TARGET)

.PHONY: release debug static shared test clean
.DELETE_ON_ERROR:

The tests were compiled with:
make test

If anything's missing, or more code is required, kindly ask in the comments.
Though, the whole code is present at: arena, assuming someone wants to compile it.
uname -a shows FreeBSD 14.0.

Extra information: The allocator has been reviewed twice by people at codereview.stackexchange.com. It is only today that I thought I'd compile it for BSD variants.

That's a lot of non-trivial code. Have you tried to use a debugger to isolate the bug?

So what's missing seems to be the setting to A5 which is hidden behind the DEBUG flag. Try making it unconditional in the C source. Speculating on source of bug: freebsd has its own make, you may have done something specific to gnu make in yours (?).

@teapot418 Precisely that. Okay, I will it out.

@teapot418 I installed gmake and now the tests pass. Previously, I was using make. The problem is solved, but I do not understand the source of the bug to write an answer. Or how I should edit the makefile for it to work for both versions of make.

@teapot418 make by itself also failed to generate an executable for the sample program that was guarded by TEST_MAIN. It seems as if it doesn't define the macros with -D in the Makefile.

I'm not following how D( if (remain) { ... } ) could be valid C code to begin with...?

@Lundin I saw R.Github_User (I have forgotten the name) suggesting this instead of #ifdef DEBUG /* CODE */ #endif in a Stackoverflow answer once. It basically replaces everything between D() with (void) 0 if DEBUG is not defined. The cast to (void) was suggested to quieten a warning, which I have now forgotten.

I think GNU is mostly a superset of the standard make. If you get it working on the freebsd one, it should work on both.

Hmm ok late in the friday afternnoon, if(remain){} does probably count as a single pp-token actually. But you couldn't do D(foo,bar) etc

@EugeneSh. The bug is solved. It was not in the code. :)

it doesn't set DEBUG with BSD make for 'test' target

Target-specific variable assignments is a GNU make specific feature.

I had never seen test: CFLAGS += -DDEBUG before. Without checking the docs, I'd say this forces DEBUG to be set for the target test. Since the code at issue was under the D macro (set if DEBUG is set), I'd say that BSD's make doesn't set DEBUG as it must because it doesn't understand this. As Ian mentioned, a GNU make feature [which I'll now remember :-)].

@IanAbbott You can probably post that as the answer to the question.

@CraigEstey Aha, yet I'd have expected it to complain and fail instead. [This is the second program for which FreeBSD has behaved this way with me. :)]

it's not only FreeBSD, other BSD too. On portability in general: on OpenSolaris that build is failed but for other reason

@yvs2014 Perhaps that is why my current Github Actions workflow failed for OpenBSD, NetBSD, FreeBSD, and Solaris. :)

@IanAbbott Yes, that seems to be it. Do you know an alternative to this GNU extension?

@Harith "yet I'd have expected it to complain and fail instead" -- on OpenBSD it's failed with make: don't know how to make CFLAGS (prerequisite of: test) message

@yvs2014 Yes, I did receive that error on OpenBSD, and have been searching what it means for some time.

Careful ... It's used in release: CFLAGS += -O2 -s -DTEST_MAIN as well. And, debug: ... and shared: ...


BSD make does not support target-specific variable assignments such as:
release: CFLAGS += -O2 -s -DTEST_MAIN

One way around that is to pass the extra settings to a sub-make in a variable:
CFLAGS += $(EXTRA_CFLAGS)

release:
    $(MAKE) EXTRA_CFLAGS="-O2 -s -DTEST_MAIN" $(TARGET)


BSD make does not support the $^ automatic variable, so the prerequisites need to be included explicitly in the command. For example, the original:
$(SLIB_TARGET): $(TARGET).o
    $(AR) rcs $@ $^

needs to be changed to:
$(SLIB_TARGET): $(TARGET).o
    $(AR) rcs $@ $(TARGET).o



After the adjustments, the Makefile may end up something like this (I also needed to add -fsanitize=address when building $(TARGET) from $(TARGET).o when using the debug options):
CFLAGS += -std=c11
CFLAGS += -fPIC
CFLAGS += -Wall
CFLAGS += -Wextra
CFLAGS += -Werror
CFLAGS += -Wwrite-strings
CFLAGS += -Wno-unused-variable
CFLAGS += -Wno-parentheses
CFLAGS += -Wpedantic
CFLAGS += -Warray-bounds
CFLAGS += -Wno-unused-function
CFLAGS += -Wstrict-prototypes
CFLAGS += -Wdeprecated

# Add extra flags from parent $(MAKE)
CFLAGS += $(EXTRA_CFLAGS)
LDFLAGS += $(EXTRA_LDFLAGS)


TARGET := arena
TEST_TARGET := tests
SLIB_TARGET := libarena.a
DLIB_TARGET := libarena.so

RM := /bin/rm -f

release:
    $(MAKE) EXTRA_CFLAGS="-O2 -s -DTEST_MAIN" $(TARGET)

debug:
    $(MAKE) EXTRA_CFLAGS="-DTEST_MAIN -DDEBUG -g3 -ggdb -fsanitize=address,leak,undefined" \
        EXTRA_LDFLAGS="-fsanitize=address" $(TARGET)

static: $(SLIB_TARGET)

$(SLIB_TARGET): $(TARGET).o
    $(AR) rcs $@ $(TARGET).o

shared: $(DLIB_TARGET)

$(DLIB_TARGET): $(TARGET).o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(TARGET).o -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) -shared

test:
    $(MAKE) EXTRA_CFLAGS="-DDEBUG" $(TEST_TARGET)
    ./$(TEST_TARGET) --verbose=3

clean: 
    $(RM) $(TARGET) $(TEST_TARGET) $(TARGET).o $(SLIB_TARGET) $(DLIB_TARGET)

.PHONY: release debug static shared test clean
.DELETE_ON_ERROR:

Other problems are due to the conditional aspects of the build environment. I recommend changing it so that the release and debug built object files and target executable have different names (or at least different paths), so that both can be built without interfering with each other. Similarly, the code conditionally compiled with -DTEST_MAIN should be changed so that the code is placed in a separate object file than the one that is placed in the library, otherwise the main function and other stuff could and up included in the library!

Wouldn't it be easier just to use GNU make on FreeBSD? "pkg ins gmake" and then use gmake rather than make.

@PaulFloyd Yes, it is easier to do that, but I (OP) wanted to learn the problems. After these changes, and some others, I was able to port the Makefile to NetBSD, FreeBSD, OpenBSD, Solaris, and OmniOS trivially.
